# How to use href(redirect to different link) in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to open a link in new tab in reactjs.

I'm currently using  `window.open('www.google.com', '_blank')`

But this opens a new tab with root url of react app appended, eg `localhost:3000/www.google.com` instead of this, what I actually want to redirect is `www.google.com`

Is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: damn! this works, what is possible reason for this though, because my data doesn't contains https appended, or maybe some other way of resolving this. Anyways this helps. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I added an answer to add a little more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define the protocol at the start of your URL then it will redirect you rather than append to the current root:

```
window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank')
```

Note `https://` at the start

The reason for this is because the `window.open()` method doesn't just accept a URL, but it can also accept a path as its first argument. Thus, you need to explicitly state that the first argument is a URL by using the full domain, not a path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an anchor tag with `href` i.e `<a href=http....></a>`
see here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp